# cant figure out how to get this template to render properly

Tags: puppet, erb

Given the following each block

```
<%@variables.each do | index, value |%>
<%= 'export ' + index.upcase %>=<%= value.upcase%>
<%= 'export ' + index.downcase %>=<%= value.downcase%>
<%end%>
```

I need it to render like this.

[image]

however it is rendering like this

[image]

what am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use space trimming in your [non-printing tags](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_template_erb.html#non-printing-tags). Like this...

```
<%- @variables.each do | index, value | -%>
<%= 'export ' + index.upcase %>=<%= value.upcase %>
<%= 'export ' + index.downcase %>=<%= value.downcase %>
<%- end -%>
```

The `<%-` and `-%>` at the start and end of the first and last lines tells Ruby not to add a line break.

Comment: OK, I made a small edit to use `<%-` opening tags on the lines that shouldn't cause line breaks.

Comment: still does :( i edited my question with your example.

Comment: Silly question, but did you re-run Puppet after editing the template?

Comment: figured it out, its because im editing in windows which is adding the `^M` and then moving it to a linux box.. ugh.

Comment: OK, cool. Gotta love Windoze. Would you mind rolling back your edit to the question? The answer won't make sense to folks who come along later if the suggested code matches the non-working code.  :)